# Fetch input value of a CQ5 Form Text Component

Tags: aem

We want to fetch input value of a CQ5 Textbox Component used multiple times on a single page. We have added components as shown below:-

```
<cq:include path="lastname" resourcetype="demoproject/components/lastname">
<cq:include path="firstname" resourcetype="demoproject/components/firstname">
```

Where in firstname and lastname are extended cq5 form text components.

How can we get values of respective fields? We thought of giving unique ID's to each component but since we are using default CQ5 component we are not able to set different ID to each component included in our .jsp page.

Comment: I don't understand why would you need different components for each form fields. You can create a generic component that overrides the default text component and drag it into the parsys and rename form elements by using edit. You can try to drag drop form components in geomatrixx website.

You can then use FormsHelper Api , refer to getValues/getValuesAsList methods and with this you could fetch the values entered within textboxes or any other form component.

Comment: Hello Sahil, Thank You for your response. Actually we need to make server calls from individual components. When I create them through Drag and drop method I cant find the code to add server specific calls. In addition to this, I want to add function like onBlur() with cq5 components. I really appreciate your Help. Thank You

Comment: Why can't you do one thing. from the text.jsp call a generic method written in your servlet and import that class to your text.jsp, you can write your business logic in that method and then with the help of dispatcher/sendredirect you can call any other servlet or url. similaryly for onblur event you can write an onblur in text.jsp where you are generating your input tag and call a javascript method  , that method will handle all the business logic so central methods for all your needs should be created. Btw why do you need onblur?

Comment: When you drag and drop you see the CQ code, you will have to modify that code, I would suggest you to look at Form Component and Form API's for more details. The default code does not make any server calls it only takes the action supplied. Neither onblur works on text component. We used onblur for validation on form components but we used Jquery Validation framework for that.

Comment: Hi Nithalia, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hello Sahil, I am stuck with this. I have a text component in my apps folder and I have included this component with cq:include. now i want this component to behave independently in html. How can I use a sigle component dynamically . And Please respond as answer so that i can accept it. Thank YOU

Answer (score 0):

Nithalia,

If you will include a component by cq:include then you will be stuck with only one instance of it and will never be able to use it dynamically. 
You will have to drag multiple instances of this text component into the Parsys and then will have to configure each of that instance individually. A component when dragged into Parsys is independent of other component because a different node is created each time you drag it. While if you will include it only a single node will be created and hence editing can be made but only once.
If you want to do some research, drag the text component multiple times on Geomartixx site and configure them individually and see the nodes that will be created under the /content path.